# Grouping DataGridview in c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have the following data in datagridview in c# winforms:

---

### Column A   |   Column B   |   Column C | Group

```
 Register 1  |       10,00     |       15,00 | Group 1
 Register 2  |       10,00     |       15,00 | Group 1
 Register 3  |       10,00     |       15,00 | Group 2
 Register 4  |       10,00     |       15,00 | Group 2
```

I want to get this in the following form:

---

### Column A   |   Column B   |   Column C

**Group 1**
     Register 1  |       10,00     |       15,00
     Register 2  |       10,00     |       15,00
**Group 1**
     Register 3  |       10,00     |       15,00
     Register 4  |       10,00     |       15,00

I dont want to use multiple datagridviews

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in WinForms DGV does not support grouping. Here is an article where someone has added this functionality themselves (note that I have not used this myself and so am not making a recommendation): http://blogs.vbcity.com/hotdog/archive/2008/12/19/9226.aspx

Alternately there are countless third-party DGV controls for sale. Infragistics has an excellent one that I can recommend which does provide grouping: http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wingrid.aspx#Overview

Answer (score 0):

These steps may possibly help:

Set AutoGenerateColumns to false. 
  Create an additional TextBoxColumn which will display the Grouped column heading. 
  Generate the other columns. 
  Use appropriate queries to bind to the grouped data.

Comment: Could you be more specific on "Appropriate Queries". I have all the data into a datatable and dont want to make additional queries to DB. If you have any sample for manipulating from DB, that will be great.

Comment: Can you bind to that data table?

Comment: Currently I am binding the datatable to the datagridview. I am not so sure what you mean by binding to the that datatable.