# Can datagridviews have multiple column headers in c#?

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to have a datagridview with multiple column headers?

For example Have a column header in the top it normally is and then have one in the middle  of the table aswell?

[image]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5143314/944681) might answer your question..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

## No

But the question is, what's your question? If you're trying to freeze the header row, in order to facilitate scrolling through data grid, then then answer is, yes you can. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Also, if you want to nest header columns (column groups), then the answer is again, yes you can. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530036/grouping-datagridview-in-c-sharp-winforms).

And at last if you do need to have tow header columns in **ONE** grid, then you have to create a custom control.

Comment: Well basically, I had 3 different tables. 2 had the same column headers, the other one was different. Nevertheless, I wanted to show them all in one DATAGRIDVIEW element, which I did. But the problem is obviously that the column header for the datagrid view is only appropriate for the first table. The second and third table are in this datagridview but the column header on the top is not the right type for them as they have different column names.